# Security and location for Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, microsoft-edge

I have have several websites with one order system for all. On one of them (can call it PRODUCTS) I have next problem, because I don't want users to see that they are paying on other website (can call it BILLING) I am calling it in a iframe page. There I call the link from Billing with some parameters so Billing know from which website and what product. After this in iframe user will chose some specification of the product and in next page will fill some form with personal data. 
All the system work perfect, my problem started some weeks ago when I got complaint from user that in Edge browser when they open the ordering from ifram you see the page, parameters are passed good, but when you click on next the page it is not passing data to next page on BILLING it is just redirect to main page. This is happening only in Edge ( Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 ). Function for redirect to next page on BILLING look like this

```
function redirect($url) {
    if (!headers_sent()){
        header("Location:".$url, TRUE, 307); 

    }else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';

    }
}
```

all forms in the BILLING order system have submit like this

```
<form action='/wizard-save-data.html' method='get' name='saveWizardData' class='fdCheckbox-checkDomain fdCheckbox-addDomain' id="autoSubmit">

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='wizard-save-data.html?page=2'" value="continue in the order" />

</form>
```

I found out on some forums that is possible next situation, because I am in iframe some security rules of Edge detect my redirect like some harming activity for user because is redirect to `location` and it is on other site then the location of PRODUCTS. Can someone share the same experience or some things I can test? This system work for all other popular browsers. Open for any ideas

```
/* UPDATE */
```

I built a small site just for this test and even if I have the order and the billing on the same site (location) then I have the same problem. SO it is not security of edge and I am total lost.

Comment: Too many possible answers - you could look at a direct integration system like SagePay Direct where you talk to their API using cURL; but that means you're capturing card details on your own site and therefore have to be PCI compliant. Or you could look at Ingenico's FlexCheckout which is built with iframe integration as an option so *should* work. Or use PayPal checkout where they deal with everything but at least it's a known brand.

Comment: @CD001 I don't want to solve the paying methods problem, because I have implemented them after the order is finish, my problem is passing all needed data to order system where I have several online methods and bank transfer

Comment: I'm not sure what payment gateway you're using but every one I've integrated allows you to specify a final *return URL* which gets called when the transaction is finished. The payment gateway will redirect (or post) data back to that final URL which allows you to finalize the order based on that response (e.g. payment may have been rejected). I'm not entirely clear on your current process - but from what you've shown here it doesn't *seem* like the right approach.

Comment: @CD001 maybe my description in not clear, but I don't have problem with payment system,  my problem is passing data from one page to other via iframe and this is not working in Edge only, in other browser work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that because of some rules in Edge browser you cant have truncated on `location.href` link so now to solve and to make it working for all types of browser it become

```
<form action='/wizard-save-data.html' method='get' name='saveWizardData' class='fdCheckbox-checkDomain fdCheckbox-addDomain' id="autoSubmit">

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='www.test.com/order/wizard-save-data.html?page=2'" value="continue in the order" />

</form>
```